# Why can't I quote ant arguments?

Tags: ant, arguments, quoting

I'm trying to run an ant target specifying an argument with spaces and it's just not working (only using the first word). I'm sure I've done this many times before without incident.

```
ant myTarget -Dmy.property="Three Word Argument" -d
```

Will yeild a line in the output like

Setting ro project property: my.property -> Three

What's going on. It *seems* to have "broken" after my upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04, but that doesn't sound like a likely culprit to me...

I'm running ant 1.7.1, and the above ant command will provide enough output to solve this issue...

I've tried

- updating ant to be `#!/bin/bash`
- using `Three\ Word\ Property` and all sorts of combinations...

Comment: Can you post the part of your build file where you're trying to set the property ?

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 with Ant 1.8.2, executing `ant init -Dmy.property="Three Word Agument"` with target `<target name="init"><echo message="${my.property}" /></target>` resulted in the output: `[echo] Three Word Argument`

Comment: Yeah, same here - that's why I wanted to see what @Stephen is doing in his build file.

Comment: This is nothing to do with my build file. It's everything to do with command line parameters which are not meant to be specified in a property file or build script so that they are conciously set. e.g. You only need an empty build.xml (`touch build.xml`) to show this issue.

Comment: So it seems to be something crazy with my ant

Answer (score 1):

Found it - I had an old alias that ended up earlier on the path that was of the form

```
#!/bin/bash
~/development/Ant/bin/ant $@
```

Changing to `~/development/Ant/bin/ant "$@"` works.

Why do this you ask? Because with multiple ants on the command line it gets really tedious referencing full paths all the time (and `ANT_HOME` is super-sticky to the point of really breaking stuff).

Of course, symbolic links work too, which is what I've replaced the above with.